# Custom share icon without Action bar

Tags: android, android-intent

I don't want to use action bar in my application. I have custom share icon in my activity. Now on click of that icon i should open a list of applications, same as we get in ShareActionProvider.

If i use:-

```
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share Image!"));
```

It opens default chooser activity pausing my activity and chooser activity comes at top.

If i use `ShareActionProvider` , it works fine but this is only for ActionBars.

How can i have same functionality as `ShareActionProvider`, but not in Action Bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the code to share an image to all available share applications on the device it would be something like this:

```
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Uri phototUri = Uri.parse(localAbsoluteFilePath);

    File file = new File(phototUri.getPath());

    Log.d(TAG, "file path: " +file.getPath());

    if(file.exists()) {
        // file create success

    } else {
        // file create fail
    }
    shareIntent.setData(phototUri);
    shareIntent.setType("image/png");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, phototUri);
    activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image!"), Navigator.REQUEST_SHARE_ACTION);
```

Comment: Thanks @erik. This method creates a chooser which pauses and hides my application and comes on top acquiring full screen. I wanted list of the available share applications as a list on right hand side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution for this.

```
ListView lv;
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
share.setType("image/png");
List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
Collections.sort(launchables, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm)); 

adapter=new AppAdapter(pm, launchables);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here, launchables list will contain all the available share applications. This we can populate in our listView using adapters.

Thanks